# issues with form and emails in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have the following code that is executed when I hit the submit button (POST request action):

```
public function earlySignupAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'password')
        ->getForm();

    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $userRepository = $em->getRepository('SiteUserBundle:User');
        $userFoundByUsername = $userRepository->findOneBy(array('username' => $user->getUsername()));

        if ($userFoundByUsername) {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', "Already registered!\n We will notify you soon!");
        } else {
            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            $session->set('user', $user);
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('SiteMainBundle_signup_additional_info'));
    }else{
        foreach($form->getErrors() as $key => $error){
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', $error->getMessage());
        }    
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ShopiousMainBundle_signup_fail'));
}
```

Inside the twig I have the following:

```
<form id="registerMiniForm" class="clearfix"  action="{{ path('SiteMainBundle_early_signup') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(userForm) }} novalidate>
                        {{ form_widget(userForm.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'validate[required,minSize[3]] arvo-regular', 'placeholder': 'Username'} }) }}
                        {{ form_widget(userForm.password, { 'attr': {'class': 'validate[required] arvo-regular', 'placeholder': 'Password'} }) }}
                        {{ form_widget(userForm.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'validate[required,custom[email],ajax[ajaxEmailCall]] input', 'placeholder': 'Email'} }) }}
                        {{ form_rest(userForm) }}
                        <div class="register-wrap">
                            <input class="arvo-bold button" type="submit" value="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

When I tried to print the $user variable, I don't see any email, why?

```
class Site\UserBundle\Entity\User#367 (47) { protected $id => NULL protected $firstname => NULL protected $lastname => NULL protected $dni => NULL protected $birthday => NULL protected $website => NULL protected $biography => NULL protected $address => NULL protected $city => NULL protected $state => NULL protected $zipcode => NULL protected $phone => NULL protected $isFirstTimeAuthUsingFB => bool(true) protected $facebookId => NULL protected $profilePicture => NULL protected $shop => NULL protected $notification => NULL protected $shippingInfo => NULL protected $shoppingCart => NULL protected $paymentInfo => NULL private $followers => NULL private $following => NULL protected $invitedFriends => NULL protected $itemlikes => NULL protected $likeCount => int(0) protected $itemComments => NULL protected $commentCount => int(0) protected $shopTestimonials => NULL private $fullName => NULL protected $username => string(11) "alksdjasdla" protected $usernameCanonical => string(11) "alksdjasdla" protected $email => NULL protected $emailCanonical => NULL protected $enabled => bool(false) protected $salt => string(31) "jjkgwyjbnv488ccskk80wkc8gk4w080" protected $password => string(14) "lkasjdaslkdasd" protected $plainPassword => NULL protected $lastLogin => NULL protected $confirmationToken => NULL protected $passwordRequestedAt => NULL protected $groups => NULL protected $locked => bool(false) protected $expired => bool(false) protected $expiresAt => NULL protected $roles => NULL protected $credentialsExpired => bool(false) protected $credentialsExpireAt => NULL }
```

Comment: because the `Site\UserBundle\Entity\User` class does not have an email property?

Comment: @WouterJ no email is there as a property. I am using FOSUserBundle

Comment: @adit if you're using FOSUserBundle you should take a look how they do the signup. IIRC you should create the user using the User Manager instead of `new User`

Comment: @Maks3w but why is the email the only one missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$user is not persisted and flushed to database after bind the properties

Add the `persist()` and `flush()` calls close this lines

```
 $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
 $session->set('user', $user) ;

 $em->persist($user);
 $em->flush();
```

Comment: I don't want to persist and flush the User entity. I wanted to store this into the session first, before the user will be redirected to a new page, which has some additional form to fill. Then after this 2nd form, I will then persist and flush the user.

Comment: funny thing is that the password is there also the username is there as well as you can see from the var_dump, but the email is not